# How to make a String become a File[]?

Tags: java, android

In `MainActivity` class, I have a file array declared as below where `getExternalFilesDirs()` is from `ContextWrapper` class.

```
File[] fs = getExternalFilesDirs(null);
```

Now, I don't want to write `getExternalFilesDirs` in `MainActivity` class, instead, I want to define the `getExternalFilesDirs()`  as a `String` in .so file. So I do as below in cpp folder.

```
JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
Java_com_test_MainActivity_callDirs(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "getExternalFilesDirs(null)");
}
```

Then in `MainActivity` class, I call `callDirs()`  which return `getExternalFilesDirs(null)`.

What I tried so far to call:

```
File[] fs = callDirs();
```

> Error :  required File[], found String.

How to make the String `getExternalFilesDirs(null)` as a File[]?

Comment: Your code doesn't begin to make sense. You're returning the name of a function instead of its return value, and then assuming that it *is* the return value. You don't need to write JNI code to list files in a directory: see `File.listFiles()`. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: People who down vote should explain at least. I have no idea

Comment: @EJP yes thats why I ask how to call a function named getExternalFilesDirs(null) if all I got is String. I don't want to write it in normal Java class because it can be seen after reverse engineering.

Comment: Returning it as a string makes it even more liable to reverse engineering. Unclear what you're asking, or why.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    File file = new File(getExternalFilesDirs(null).toString());
    File[] fileArray = file .listFiles();
```

Comment: `File file = new File(callDirs().toString());
                File[] fileArray = file.listFiles();`

Comment: i think callDirs().toString() is null. check plese

Comment: Done check, callDirs().toString() is not null.

Comment: try "new File(getExternalFilesDirs(null).toString()).exists() "

Comment: maybe that paths no has file

Comment: File[] fs = getExternalFilesDirs(null); has file. This path is not null.